# Git: how to ignore file with unchanged content?

Tags: git

To force an align with a coworker I copied an entire project into my project folder, excluding .git folder.

Now ALL files are marked as modified, but 99.9% are without any changes in content. How can I discard all files in which there are no content changes?

Comment: Use `git reset --hard` to return to the last commit

Comment: May be you should pull from his branch instead of blindly copying the source code

Comment: Are theses marked changes cause of different line ending settings? e.g. he uses Mac and you Windows or vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make a `git clone` or copy it with the .git directory

## Explanation:

If you only copy the project without the .git directory where are the commits saved, git thinks the aren't any commits, because it made a new .git directory, where aren't any commits saved.

Comment: i cannot clone (long story) but copying with that `.git` directory saved my work. After copy, I overwrite copied folder with my modified files an so I can do a `git merge` in normal conditions. Thanks !